# Custom Encoding with NSData, initializes but crashes

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, decode, encode

I've spent some serious time debugging this problem and I am stumped.

I'm trying to pack custom objects tightly into `NSData` to save space when they are saved to disk.  I have implemented custom encoding and decoding methods for these custom objects.  When I pack and unpack the objects, everything is initialized properly according to the debugger.  Immediately after the code runs, it has either an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1` or `code=2`.

Here is the encoding and decoding:

```
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _memConstants = [[DWMemoryConstants alloc]init];

        int arraySize = _memConstants.chunkSize * _memConstants.chunkSize;
        NSData* unencodedBlocks[arraySize];
        [data getBytes:unencodedBlocks];

        _blocks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            DWBlock *block = [[DWBlock alloc]initWithData:unencodedBlocks[i]];
            [_blocks setObject:block forKey:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(block.blockName)]];

            if (i == 0) {
                _position = CGPointFromString(block.chunkName);
            }
        }
        _chunkName = NSStringFromCGPoint(_position);
        _bounds = CGRectMake(_position.x * _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth,
                             _position.y * _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth,
                             _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth,
                             _memConstants.chunkSize * kBlockSpriteWidth);
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSData *) customEncode {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    NSData* blocks[_blocks.allValues.count];
    int count = 0;
    for (DWBlock *block in _blocks.allValues) {
        blocks[count] = [block customEncode];
        count++;
    }
    [data appendBytes:&blocks length:sizeof(blocks)];

    return data;
}
```

The exception happens at the end of this code.  It successfully prints all of the log messages first, and I have verified that there is nothing wrong with the Chunk object:

```
-(void) testEncodeDecode {
    DWChunk *testChunk = [[DWChunk alloc]initWithPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
    NSData *testData = [testChunk customEncode];
    NSLog(@"datasize= %@", testData);
    DWChunk *unencodedChunk = [[DWChunk alloc]initWithData:testData];
    NSLog(@"blocks=%@", unencodedChunk.blocks.allValues);
    NSLog(@"this message will print");
}
```

As I said, all of the variables for the Chunk and Block objects are properly initialized. I suspect that the problem is related to improper releasing of objects, but I don't know where to go from here.

**Edit: I have enabled checking for zombies, and now I get this error message:**

`2014-10-24 11:38:31.775 DigWorld[10622:60b] *** -[NSConcreteMutableData release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x81790710`

Comment: BTW are you using ARC ?

Comment: Yes the project is ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
My initial thoughts where technically incorrect (read the code too fast...), but the actual error is along the exact same lines. By saving `blocks`, you save only the array of pointers, and not the actual data. You can make sure of that: in your comment you say that `sizeof(blocks)=3600` and `_blocks.allValues.count=900`, so you only save the 900 pointers (* 4 bytes/pointer = 3600 bytes)

The actual data as created by `[block customEncode]` is then disposed of by ARC.

When reading this array afterward, you get pointers to pieces of memory (formerly `NSData`) that have been marked as freed, producing your crash, and explaining the error message when enabling zombies.

The tricky part: since this is the same instance of the program, and encode and decode are run next to each other, the actual memory has not been reallocated/overwritten. So you get the impression the objects are correctly saved. But rest assured this memory will eventually be overwritten by something else. You can make sure of that by saving the `NSData` on disk and decoding it on a re-run of the program.

---

It seems to me that you are trying to reinvent the wheel here. 
The [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html) protocol has been created exactly for that purpose: persisting graphs of objects on disk. The [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html) class will give you serialisation to disk with flexibility, and platform-independance, in a well-tested and documented interface.

You should be leveraging that architecture. Even if you decide that `NSKeyedArchiver` creates archives too "big" for your purposes, use the architecture in place and create your own archiver.

If you choose to do so, you can get inspiration [with this open source `NSCoder` subclass implementation](https://github.com/FlorianDenis/Serial-Archiver)  (disclaimer: I wrote it)

Comment: Of course I have already implemented saving the files to disk with NSCoding, however the file sizes are huge compared to the number of bytes contained in the raw data I am trying to custom encode.

Comment: Also, sizeof(blocks) says 3600 bytes.  I am confused by how this can be the problem when all of the block objects and the chunk object are properly initialized to the correct values.

Comment: I read way too quickly for my own good... I maintain using `NSCoding` and implementing a different way of coding is the way to go though. Have a look at the serial archiver, it should introduce minimum overhead

Comment: I will take a look. I appreciate the feedback. I have made a slight edit to my question, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: It does, I think I got it. What is the value of `_blocks.allValues.count` ?

Comment: In this case it will be 900.

Comment: What is really strange is that when I call `[block customEncode]`, the `NSData` object that it returns is 28 bytes.  Then when I add it to the array of `blocks[]`, it changes it to 4 bytes.  I would love to find a workaround for this just for my sanity!

Comment: You are not appending the `NSData` to your array. Your array is an array of `NSData*`, i.e. *pointers* to `NSData` (which are 4B in size on 32 bits systems). Using such an array is unconventional in the first place. If you insist on persisting that way, why not create a `NSMutableData` and use `appendData:` for each `[block customEncode]` ?